# c++: switch statement missing semicolon before close brace

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compiler-errors, switch-statement

In the interest of future readers and my own sanity later, I like to make it absolutely clear that `switch` statements that do not have a `default` case (due to all cases being covered) or sequential `if-elseif-else` with a final else that should not do anything must not be omitted and a comment to that effect be included (see example).

However, whenever I include the `default` case in the `switch` statement and leave it empty I must put a semicolon inside the `default` case or a compiler error: " Line [Line of closing brace of switch statement]`missing ';' before '}'" occurs. ***WHY?!***

**EXAMPLE: GENERATES COMPILER ERROR**

```
switch(direction) {
    case MOVE_UP:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_RIGHT:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_DOWN:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_LEFT:
    //...
    break;
    default:
        /* DO NOTHING */
}
```

**EXAMPLE: DOES NOT GENERATE COMPILER ERROR**

```
switch(direction) {
    case MOVE_UP:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_RIGHT:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_DOWN:
    //...
    break;
    case MOVE_LEFT:
    //...
    break;
    default:
        /* DO NOTHING */;
}
```

Comment: FYI the default case is optional in C++ ...

Comment: If you want to be consistent, put a `break;` after the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

6.1/1 in C++03 gives the grammar for a labeled-statement:

```
labeled-statement:
    identifier : statement
    case constant-expression : statement
    default : statement
```

C++11 is the same except you can have attributes before the label.

A zero-length sequence of tokens is not a *statement* in C++, hence `default:` on its own is not a *labeled-statement*.

That said, I don't know what the motivation was why the grammar for a *labeled-statement* doesn't allow `default: statementopt`. If it did then there  would be a grammatical ambiguity if you wrote `default : case 1: break;`, whether `case 1: break;` is the *statement* belonging to `default:`, or whether `default:` has no *statement* of its own, but is immediately followed by one. There's still no doubt what it *means*, but maybe it was thought that it would mess up people's parsers.

Answer (score 12):

Because you need a statement for your `default` case. A semicolon is an empty-statement.